# How to make a TypeScript property runtime readonly?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can create a compile-time readonly property by using the `readonly` keyword. But it is still writable by other JavaScript code during runtime.

I can create a runtime readonly property in JavaScript with the following code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(obj, "key", {
    value: value,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false
});
```

So how can I achieve the same in TypeScript with more simple code?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript, any Javascript code is still valid in Typescript...

Comment: Typescript compiles down to javascript. Javascript doesn't have readonly properties. So, it would be impossible for Typescript to make a readonly property.

Comment: @BrunoMarotta It is possible to set readonly properties in JavaScript with `Object.defineProperty` as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @BJRINT so how can I make it work in TypeScript, class constructors must initialize all properties in the class, but it doesn't seem to recognize `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBJJzN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: As explained here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44357, typescript doesn't convert readonly to ECMA property with writable false, because a readonly property should be mutable in the constructor. So, answering your question: no, there is no simple code in typescript to do so. You have to write the same code you are writing in javascript (defineProperty, etc.)